# What is the exact names of three kinds of variable in shell script? (Global Environment vs Global vs Local)

Tags: bash, global-variables, local-variables

I read a lot of explanation of kinds of variable in bash shell script.
But I still confused because people uses mixed terminology for the same thing.

From my knowledge there are three kinds of variable even though I don't know exact official term for that.
I will define the name of them like belows for the clear communication.

1. Global Environment Variable
   This is variable exported so that the whole script can access and child shell also can access
2. Global Variable
   This is variable that can access in whole script scope but not all child shell.
3. Local Variable
   This is variable that can acess only in a function scope. This variable defined with "local" keyword

Some people distinguish Global or Local by the point of that it is exported or not. They call the "2. Global Variable" as "Local Variable"

But some people distinguish Global or Local by the point of that it is function scope or the whole script scope.

What is exact official terminoloies for these three kinds of variables?
And what is the exact distinction for these?

For example,

```
$ cat vartest.sh
#!/bin/bash
var2="global_var2"
echo $var1   # (1)
echo $var2   # (2)

$ var1="local_var1"
$ source ./vartest.sh
local_var1
global_var2
```

I think var1 in (1) and var2 in (2) are totally same kind of variable. I can't find any difference between them.

Is it any different between (1) and (2) under the hood?

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from above(or below) comments because comment doesn't have formatting function.

```
    $ var1="local variable"
    $ echo $SHLVL     # echo shell level
    1
    $ bash            # initiate sub-shell
    $ echo $SHLVL
    2                 # this tells you are in sub-shell
    $ echo $var1      # try to access local var from parent shell
    
    $ exit            # exit from sub-shell
    $ echo $SHVL      # confirm you are back to parent shell
    1
    $ export var1     # export 'var1' to environmental(global) variable
    $ bash            # initiate sub-shell again
    $ echo $SHLVL     # confirm you are in sub-shell
    2
    $ echo $var1      # now you can access this variable
    local variable
    $ exit
```

Here is another example on working with local (shell) variable in a script.

```
# Create a script as follow.
   $ cat test.sh
   #!/bin/bash
   echo "Shell level is $SHLVL"
   echo "var2 is $var2"
-----
   $ bash test.sh      # Run the script
Shell level is 2       # $SHLVL is accessible in all-level because it's environmental/global variable.
var2 is                # var2 is empty because it's not created yet.

   $ var2="passing var" bash test.sh
Shell level is 2
var2 is passing var    # shell(local) variable is passed to the sub-shell/script
```

In a shell, global variable *is* environmental variable accessible in all-level. Local variable is only accessible in a current shell. And you can *export* local variable to global/environmental variable. I hope this clarifies a bit.

Comment: I add my exaple code in the original question for clear understanding

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused between shell environment and scripting.
Try following links.

- https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html
- https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/localvar.html

Comment: From your link, it explains local and global variable in both shell environment and scripting. Then what is different between local var in shell environment and global var in scripting? I don't catch any difference between them.

Comment: `ENV_LOCAL="env_local"` `function  vartest { script_global="SCRIPT_GLOBAL"; echo $ENV_LOCAL; }` Then If I run `vartest` I can get `env_local` and if I run `echo $script_global` then I can get `SCRIPT_GLOBAL` What is the difference?

Comment: You forgot `local` keyword in your function. `function  vartest { local script_global="SCRIPT_GLOBAL"; echo $ENV_LOCAL; } `, and access local variable `$script_global` outside of function. You can't, because `$script_global` is declared as local.

Comment: I already know what the local keyword is. I mean script_global is global variable in scripting point of view, but it seems to be local in shell environment point of view. Can you tell the difference between them?

Comment: Local variable (in function) cannot be accessed from outside of function. `x="global var"; function vartest { local x="local var"; echo $x; }; vartest; echo $x` In this example, `x` is declared in both outside and inside of function. When you run `vartest`, you can access `local x`, but not globally declared `x`. And if you access `x` outside of function, result is the other way. When your script gets large, you will find your functions sometime interfere globally declared variables resulting unexpected results. It's always good idea to isolate variables in functions.

Comment: Thanks for your kind explanation. But I already know what you mean. I will ask my point using your example. In the frist line of your example, you declare `x="global var"`, but it can be told as local by [link](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html) that you mentioned because it is not exported and only be able to be accessed in current shell. I can't find any difference between local variable in shell env and global var in shell scripting.

Comment: It's "local variable" in a function. When you declare `local x="local var"` within a function, this local variable will not be accessible from the rest of the script. It's only available to the "local" to that function only. The scope of global variable is to all script. The scope of local variable is to a function which it was declared.

Comment: Hm you still misunderstanding my point. I already completely understand what is your `local x="local var"` means. Let's focus on your `x="global var"` again you told it's global because it can be accessible from the rest of the script. But please go back to [link](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html) "3.2.1.2. Local variables" and read it. Can you tell the difference between `x="global var"` vs `local variables in 3.2.1.2. Local Variables` ? Local variables introduced in 3.2.1.2 still be accessible from the rest of the script.

Comment: I see your point. And that section in the article can be confusing. Because I basically gave you that article without context.  That article is about bash shell (not scripting), describing difference between environmental variables and local variables. It's "local" to current shell only. When you run a bash script, bash initiate another shell(sub-shell) and run your script under it. Then your sub-shell doesn't have access to variables of your current shell, because it's "local" to your current shell. You need to `export` local shell, then your sub-shell have access to your variables.

Comment: Try `echo $SHLVL`. It's environmental variable for shell-level. It should return `1`.  Type `bash` and press enter. And then run `echo $SHLVL` again. It should return `2`. Because you are in sub-shell. `exit` and try following, `x="local to current shell"; bash`. Press enter, and `echo $x`. You will see `$x` is empty, because it's local to parent shell. `exit` again, then do `export x` and initiate another sub-shell, by `bash`. Then run `echo $SHLVL; echo $x`. It will print out `2`, identifying your are in sub-shell. And it also sees `$x` printing out its content.

Comment: I really appreciate your kind patient explanation, but I already completely understand local and global in environmental variable. My point is local environmental  variable vs global script variable. These two variable has any differences? local environmental variable can be read/write in script exactly same with global variable in script. It seems to be same to me.